# Irrelevant syntax issue in apiblueprint

Tags: web-services, rest, apiblueprint

So I've been designing this REST API using apiary.io and I'm almost done.
There is this syntax issue that I get which doesn't make sense at all.
I have a [GET] action for a specific resource But It seems like apiary confuses it with a [GET] action for another resource and says

```
Action with method 'GET' already defined for resource '/api/quotes?{sq}&{author_id}&{ratingrange}&{quoteidrange}&{authorratingrange}&{authoridrange}'
```

Here is the API link :

https://app.apiary.io/kalematie/editor

the syntax issue is in line 987

I would like to know whether I'm doing something wrong or there's a bug in the tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this still happening?

Comment: I don't know its been a while since I last used apiary.